# Странный баг с переводом в очереди проверок

Tags: дефект, локализация, очередь-проверок

В очереди проверок есть странный баг с переводом.

Сначала все нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда ставлю минус (обратите внимание `Score of -1`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю когда сниму минус то все снова будет нормально, но нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это за баг?

Comment: Уже есть на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387651/339911)